# Why am I finding duplicates of directories (folders)?

Tags: files, directory, bugs

On my Manjaro Linux installation, I sometimes find partial duplicates of folders.  In each case, the original folder has as many duplicates as it has characters in it's title minus 1.  Each duplicate is the name of the previous folder with the last character removed.

For example, the folder `~/.local/share/dolphin-emu` is a folder (for the dolphin emulator) which has 10 partial duplicates in `~/.local/share/`, with the following names:

```
dolphin-em
dolphin-e
dolphin-
dolphin
dolphi
dolph
dolp
dol
do
d
```

All of these directories contain a subdirectory called "shared2", which was copied from "dolphin-emu".  However, "dolphin-emu" contains other subdirectories that were not copied.

Also, there was already a folder called "dolphin" for the KDE Dolphin file manager.  This folder now contains the copied "shared2" in addition to the "view_properties" directory which was originally in the "dolphin" folder, which means the old folder has merged with the copied one.

Unfortunately, I don't have any other examples of this on hand, as I deleted the others I found awhile back. But each case of this had a similar pattern.  As far as I remember, they only had one file or subdirectory copied from the original folder.  It's unclear why this only happened to certain folders, as the other I remember was a hidden folder in my home folder.

Does anyone have any idea of how these duplicates were generated?

Comment: can you share the long list output... we might get some clue..